# Finding Riemannian metric from this geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

In a $d$-dimensional Riemannian manifold, given a geodesic equation $\gamma^i(t)=a^i\phi(tb^i),i\in 1\ldots d$, where $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is an increasing function, $a^i,b^i$ are constants, is it possible to determine a Riemannian metric (and the corresponding Christoffel symbols) that derives such a geodesic?

Comment: I don't think so (in general). If I recall correctly, one must know parallel transport along **all** curves in order to recover the connection (and hence if the connection is Riemannian, the metric).

Comment: Actually, I am not sure if my previous comment helps. Assuming that all geodesics on your manifold have that particular form, then I believe the Christoffel symbols can be found in terms of the derivatives of $\phi$ directly from the geodesics equation. I believe what you get is $$ a^k \left( b^k \right)^2 \ddot{\phi} \left( t b^k \right) + a^i b^i a^j b^j \dot{\phi} \left( t b^i \right) \dot{\phi} \left( t b^j \right) \Gamma^k_{ij} = 0$$

Comment: @o0BlueBeast0o Does that mean that for any manifold, if the geodesics are given, then one can find a metric corresponding to the latter?